# How to know when to use a binomial coefficient?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> I'm preparing myself for a final and keep getting confused when I should use a binomial coefficient vs simply taking a number to a certain power.

**For example, here are two different problems:**

1. Suppose that we are selecting four tiles from a set of nine: four red, three blue, and
   two green.

   (a) How many different sets of tiles can we draw?
2. A certain electronic lock has six buttons labelled A through F. A combination for this
   lock consists of a five-letter string.

   (a) How many different possible combinations does this lock admit?

**1)** would use (9 over 4) = 9!/4!(9-4)! = 126, while **2)** would use 6^5 = 7776

A lot of times I find myself mixing the two up... which leads to the wrong answer. Can somebody please explain (and dumb it down a bit) when to use one or the other? Thank you!

Comment: In your first example, I don't see how $\binom{9}{4}$ is correct, unless the colors are a red herring and the tiles are distinguishable in some other manner.  If any two red tiles are identical, you are not choosing four distinguished objects from among nine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binomial coefficient is when you need to choose options from a selection and order is not important. So in the second case, the order of the elements is important, because ABCDE is not the same as ABCED.

If you are choosing tiles, it does not matter which order you choose them in. You may first choose four red tiles and 1 blue, but this is identical to choosing the blue first and the reds after.

Essentially, with your "Binomial Coefficient", you are dividing by the $(n-r)!$ term to remove the repeats that come when the order of choice is taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (1) is
$$
\sum_{\substack{n_1,n_2,n_3\ge 0\\\color{red}{n_1}+\color{blue}{n_2}+\color{green}{n_3}=4}}{\binom{\color{red}{4}}{n_1}\binom{\color{blue}{3}}{n_2}\binom{\color{green}{2}}{n_3}}=\binom{9}{4}=126
$$
if all the tiles are distinct. But if the tiles of each color are indistinguishable, then all you have is the number of tiles of each color, so you're counting weak compositions $n_1+n_2+n_3=4$, where $0\le n_1\le 4$, $0\le n_2\le 3$, $0\le n_3\le 2$. Those are
$$
\begin{split}
4&=4+0+0\\
4&=3+1+0\\
4&=3+0+1\\
4&=2+2+0\\
4&=2+1+1\\
4&=2+0+2\\
4&=1+3+0\\
4&=1+2+1\\
4&=1+1+2\\
4&=0+3+1\\
4&=0+2+2
\end{split}
$$
All together, $11$ compositions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is confusing, because it is not clear if a set containing the first green tile is different from the same set substituting the second green tile instead. So let us change the example. You are asked to pick 4 tiles out of 9 different tiles. Then the answer is $9\choose 4$. Here is how I think about this:

For my first choice, I can pick any of the 9 tiles. Then I only have 8 tiles left, so for the second choice, I have 8 options, and so on. So I can pick in $9\times 8\times7\times6 = 9!/(9-4)!$ different ways. But at the end, the order of my choice does not affect which subset I picked. So we have to divide the answer by the number of different orderings of the 4 objects, that is $4!$. The final answer is then $$\frac{9!}{(9-4)!4!} = {9\choose 4}.$$

For the second example, there are two differences:

1. Your choice for the first letter does not restrict the choice for the second one. That is, if you pick A for the first letter, you can still pick A for the second letter.
2. The string is an ordered set of letters. We pick the letters in the order. So we don't have the complication that we had in the first example about dividing by the number of orderings.

So here is how I think about the second question. For the first letter, I have 6 choices, for the second, I still have 6 choices, and so on. Therefore, I have $6\times 6 \times 6\times6\times6 = 6^5$ choices.